# How to find the GCR LDAP server administrator ID to configure the Enterprise Workload Manager on z/OS?

Tags: zos

How to find the GCR LDAP server administrator ID to configure the Enterprise Workload Manager on z/OS?

I am looking for the value of the Global Configuration Repository (GCR) LDAP server administer ID to configure the Enterprise Workload Manager on z/OS. 
This is about an paramter, which is used to enter the "installEWLM" command. Do anybody have an example for the Global Configuration Repository (GCR) LDAP server administer ID?
While searching, I just found, in another case, that for the LDAP user is used "cn=root".

I am working with the manual [http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/eserver/v1r2/index.jsp?topic=%2Fewlminfo%2Feicaainstallewlmzos.htm](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/eserver/v1r2/index.jsp?topic=/ewlminfo/eicaainstallewlmzos.htm) (GCR required on page 169).

Thanks!